# If $f(z)$ is analytic, is $f(-z)$ also analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you have a function $f(z)$ that is analytic. Is it true that $f(-z)$ is also analytic?

Comment: Yes it is true...

Comment: @Hirak Is it really true?

Answer (score 4):

It $f$ is analytic on a domain $\Omega$ and $-z \in \Omega$ for all $z \in \Omega$, then your statement is true.

Consider the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z + i},$$
which is analytic on $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{-i\}$. However,
$$f(-z) = \frac{1}{-z + i}$$
is not analytic on $\Omega$, as it has a pole at $z = i$.

Answer (score 3):

$f$ analytic means that is locally a power series:
$$f(z) = \sum a_n(z - c)^n.$$
Then,
$$f(-z) = \sum a_n((-z) - c)^n = \sum (-i)^n a_n(z + c)^n$$
is locally a power series. Warning: the *domain* will be different.

Alternatively, using that analytic iff holomorphic, your function is the composition of two holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 2):

A function $g(z)$ is analytic in an open domain $G$ iff
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} g(z) =0
\end{align}
on $G$. Define $g(z) = f(-z)=u(-x, -y)+iv(-x, -y)$ where $f(z)=u(x, y)+iv(x, y)$ is analytic on $G$, then observe
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}g(z) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f(-z) = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}(-z). 
\end{align}
Unless, $f(z)$ is also analytic on $-G$, we can't conclude $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}(-z)=0$ on $G$.

Consider the example
\begin{align}
f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z}
\end{align}
which is analytic on the right half-plane, but $g(z)= f(-z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ has a simple pole on the right half-plane.